# Templating in Terraform module - argument is not expected here

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

During the creation of the new TF module, I met the issue with *[templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile)* functionality.

In the triggers.tf I declared the module with an argument which is templated config.
The module ./modules/trigger is using provided argument (filename).

During the TF plan I'm receiving:

```
 Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on triggers.tf line 43, in module "trigger":
│   43:   filename = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/trigger.yaml.tpl", {
│
│ An argument named "filename" is not expected here.
```

**./modules/trigger/main.tf**

```
resource "null_resource" "trigger" {

  filename = var.filename

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      gcloud alpha ... --trigger_config ${self.filename}  \
EOT
  }
}
```

**triggers.tf**

```
locals {
  repos = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/repositories/repos.yaml"))
  repos = {
    for pair in setproduct([local.repos["project"]], local.repos["repos"]) : "${pair[0]}/${pair[1]}" => {
      project = pair[0]
      repo    = pair[1]
    }
  }
}

module "trigger" {
  source   = "./modules/trigger"
  for_each = local.repos

  filename = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/trigger.yaml.tpl", {
    trigger_event           = "push"
    bitbucket_project       = each.value["project"]
    bitbucket_repo          = each.value["repo"]
  })
}
```

**/repositories/repos.yaml**

```
project: test
repos:
  - cloud-test
```

**/templates/trigger.yaml.tpl**

```
name: "${trigger_event}"
project: "${bitbucket_project}"
repo: "${bitbucket_repo}"
```

Comment: You need to provide only the filename it seems, not the entire file, so you probably need two steps: create a file using a `local_file` resource and providing the path to the variable `filename`.

Comment: @MarkoE thanks for your answer! I tried the solution with yamlencode -yamlencode(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/trigger.yaml and also I received the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think `null_resource` has the `filename` argument as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes that are required for this to work:

1. Create a file using `local_file` resource
2. Update the `null_resource` in the module to use only the variable and not the non-existent argument (i.e., `filename`)

Note that renaming local variables is not allowed, so having two `repos` definitions will cause errors. I suggest changing it to something like:

```
locals {
  repositories = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/repositories/repos.yaml"))
  repos = {
    for pair in setproduct([local.repositories["project"]], local.repositories["repos"]) : "${pair[0]}/${pair[1]}" => {
      project = pair[0]
      repo    = pair[1]
    }
  }
}
```

So in the root of the module, here is what part of code you need:

```
resource "local_file" "trigger_file" {
  for_each = local.repos
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/trigger.yaml.tpl", {
    trigger_event     = "push"
    bitbucket_project = each.value["project"]
    bitbucket_repo    = each.value["repo"]
  })
  filename = "${path.module}/trigger-${each.value["project"]}.yaml"
}
```

The `local_file` resource will create as many files as you need, where the names of the files will be different depending on the project name. So for your current example this will crate a file with name `trigger-test.yaml` in the same directory. Then, in the module you are calling, the `null_resource` would change to:

```
resource "null_resource" "trigger" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      gcloud alpha ... --trigger_config ${var.filename}  \
EOT
  }
}
```

This should work if you have defined the variable `filename` in the module. Lastly, when calling the module, you can use the following code:

```
module "trigger" {
  source   = "./modules/trigger"
  for_each = local.repos

  filename = "${path.module}/trigger-${each.value["project"]}.yaml"
}
```

Comment: Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "bitbucket_project" 
How should I fix it?

Comment: Where exactly does that happen?

Comment: Above configuration getting me Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "bitbucket_project"

Comment: Which part of the configuration? Have you changed anything in the template file?

Comment: I just tested this locally and it works. Note that there wasn't a single change compared to the code from the question.